# How does Firefox know that a webpage is stored on my computer?

Tags: firefox, webserver

I use a webserver to serve a webpage over localhost. If I visit http://localhost on my machine I see this icon in Firefox's URL bar instead of the usual lock icon. Upon clicking it, it says that "This page is stored on your computer." which is true.

[image: localhost]

I added a host entry to my `hosts` file that points to the loopback address:

```
127.0.0.1 stormdesign.local
```

I then visit http://stormdesign.local and it looks like a regular site, with the crossed lock icon, despite the fact that it's the same page that is stored on my computer.

[image: stormdesign.local]

How does Firefox determine whether a page is stored on my computer or not?

My Firefox version is 79.0.

Answer (score 1):

Since in both cases the page is stored on your computer, the answer must be that
Firefox distinguishes by the textual address of the site, not by the IP address
that it is resolved into (which is `127.0.0.1`).

This means that "localhost" and "127.0.0.1" are hard-coded into Firefox,
which was perhaps easier and less work for the developer(s).

Comment: That's what I was thinking as well, but I didn't want to speculate. Could you point me towards a source that backs up your claims?

Comment: The only link would be to the Firefox source-code. See for example [this line](https://searchfox.org/mozilla-central/source/browser/locales/en-US/browser/preferences/connection.ftl#69) commented as "# Do not translate localhost, 127.0.0.1 and ::1". But there are other such hard references in the code. You may search the code using [Searchfox](https://searchfox.org/).